# Passing structure pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a structure like this

```
struct binTree{
long long data;
struct binTree *left;
struct binTree *right;
}
```

And a function like this:

```
void height(struct binTree **r)
{
    ...
    ...
    height(&(r->left));
    height(&(r->right));
    ...
    ...
}
```

Compiling the above function gives me the error like this...

```
error: request for member ‘left’ in ‘* r’, which is of non-class type ‘binTree*’
error: request for member ‘right’ in ‘* r’, which is of non-class type ‘binTree*’
```

What is the problem with the code? How to pass the pointers that I have inside the structure?

Comment: Why does the `height` function need to take `binTree **` instead of just `binTree *`? You only need double indirection if you need to be able to modify the input pointer.

Comment: I suggest you study some C++ books, to get away from C (or tag the question as C, only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write

```
height( &( ( *r )->left ) );
height( &( ( *r )->right ) );
```

Or more simpler

```
height( &( *r )->left );
height( &( *r )->right );
```

Here operators `&` and `*` are unary operators that have a less priority than postfix operators including operator `->`

P.S. As this function as I think does not change the object binTree then you could simplify the function and declare the parameter simply as

```
const struct binTree *r
```

or if it is a C++ program then

```
const binTree *r
```

In this case syntaxical constructions used in the function would be simpler.

Only i do not understand why it has return type void.:) Should not the function return the height of a binary tree or the height is outputed inside the body of the function? it would be better if the function would return the height. In this case you could for example compare heights of two  binary trees.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more clear syntax:

```
void height(struct binTree **r)
{
    struct binTree* pr = *r;
    height( &pr->right );
    height( &pr->left );
}
```